# I want to install php 5.3.9 in ubuntu 12.04 via apt-get - what repository should I add?

Tags: 12.04, server, php

I want to install php 5.3.9 in ubuntu 12.04 via apt-get.

> apt-cache show php5-fpm

only lists ***5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1*** and ***5.3.10-1ubuntu3***. There is a critical bug in 5.3.10 ( https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61045&edit=1 ) that I am trying to avoid.

Is there a repository that will let me install php 5.3.9 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Answer (score 1):

As 5.3.10 is newer than 5.3.9, even if there were a repository with 5.3.9, the 5.3.10 package would still get installed. It seems from the bug as if the bug is fixed in 5.3.12, and should apply to 5.3.10, so perhaps pushing for the patch to get included in an SRU, and helping to get that done, would be a better solution. It would then fix it for everyone, and not need a PPA for people to get it.

You can see the procedure for getting an SRU, here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates